# uninstall ubuntu 14.04 lts

Tags: uninstall

Hi I ‘m 1 day old to ubuntu, I Installed ubuntu 14.04 lts on my windows 8 on 4-may-2014, even after giving the option boot along side win 8, it over wrote win8 and starts ubuntu 14. now I  have no access to windows 8 at all neither to the files on my laptop. I tried using my windows boot recovery but nothing happened. I tried using Os uninstaller by using ubuntu boot CD with cmds “sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair” and “sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install -y os-uninstaller && os-uninstaller” but I don’t get os uninstaller, what is the right cmmds for restoring windows or atleast getting access to my files. I have tried booting With a USB bootstick also. Pls hlp

Answer (score 0):

So, you are trying to delete ubuntu and install your windows 8 back, right?

Seems like windows 8 doesn't support dual boot with ubuntu.

Boot from live usb/cd of ubuntu. Then go to gparted (application) and delete your ubuntu partition(s).

After your SSD/HDD is clean install your windows 8.

If this is not the answer your looking for, please reply.